# Product of nonsingular and full rank matrices

Tags: matrices, analysis

1. Assume that $U\in\mathbb{C}^{n\times k}$ (with $k<=n$) has full
   column rank and $A\in\mathbb{C}^{n\times n}$ is nonsingular. Is
   $U^*AU$ nonsingular?
2. Assume that $U,P\in\mathbb{C}^{n\times k}$ (with $k<=n$) have full
   column rank and $A\in\mathbb{C}^{n\times n}$ is nonsingular. Is
   $P^*AU$ nonsingular?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer to $2.)$ is no. Take

$$ A= \begin{pmatrix} 1 , 0 \\ 0 , 1 \end{pmatrix}, \quad U=\begin{pmatrix} 1 \\-1 \end{pmatrix} \quad \text{and } \quad P= \begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 1 \end{pmatrix}.$$

Clearly $A$ is nonsingular and $U, P$ have full column rank. Furthermore

$$ P^{\star} A U = \begin{pmatrix} 1 , 1 \end{pmatrix} \cdot \begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ -1\end{pmatrix}=0$$

is singular.

Answer (score 0):

I think the answer to the question 1 is no. Let
$$A=\left[\begin{array}{cc} 0 & 1\\1 & 1\end{array}\right]\qquad\text{and}\qquad U=\left[\begin{array}{c} 1\\0\end{array}\right].$$
So
$$U^*AU=0,$$
and $U^*AU$ is singular.